# Middleware Not Functioning Only on API Routes in Laravel 9.19

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-middleware, laravel-api

I have set up a project and written some routes in the `api.php` route file. I created a middleware, registered the middleware in the `Kernel.php` file, and then implemented the middleware in the `api.php` route group. However, when I hit the route, the request is not being received in the middleware. I have even followed the implementation steps from the Laravel documentation, but the problem remains the same – the request is not being received in the middleware.

##### routes/api.php

```php
Route::group(["middleware" => "api_auth"], function () {
    Route::get("/categories", ["uses" => "ApiController@getCategories"]);
    Route::get("/child/categories", ["uses" => "ApiController@getChildCategories"]);
});
```

Another method for implementing middleware in `api.php` routes

```php
Route::middleware(\App\Http\Middleware\ApiAuthentication::class)->group(function () {
    Route::get("/categories", ["uses" => "ApiController@getCategories"]);
    Route::get("/child/categories", ["uses" => "ApiController@getChildCategories"]);
});
```

##### app/Http/Kernel.php

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'api_auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\ApiAuthentication::class,
];
```

##### app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php

```php
public function boot() {
    $this->configureRateLimiting();

    $this->routes(function () {
        Route::middleware('api')
                ->middleware("throttle:30:1")// 60requests in 2 mins
                ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers')
                ->prefix('api')
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

        Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Admin')
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    });
}
```

##### app/Http/Middleware/ApiAuthentication.php

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ApiAuthentication {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next) {
        $locale = "ar";
        \Log::info("-- middware locale setting --{$locale}");
        app('translator')->setLocale($locale);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I have spent a significant amount of time on this issue but have been unable to identify the problem.

Comment: Can you also show us your middleware class? Does it have a problem only for this middleware or also for others?

Comment: Not sure if I'm correct, but might be worth a shot. What if you change the name to `apiAuth` without the underscore. And register it to the route group like `group(['middleware' => ['apiAuth'])`. Also try clearing cache and route cache `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: @VasoGamdelidze I have updated my question and now another issue is that middleware locale value at last of the request instead of first set the locale value and then process next

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Route::middleware(['api_auth'])->group(function () {
   Route::get("/categories", ["uses" => "ApiController@getCategories"]);
   Route::get("/child/categories", ["uses" => "ApiController@getChildCategories"]);
});
```

Comment: now middleware is working but locale which is set is middleware to process next according to request locale but middleware set the locale after completing the process with default locale

Comment: Try use session because setLocale isn't save permanent, so redirecting is set default value. put locale in session session()->put('locale', $locale); 

and in middleware
if(session()->has('locale')) {
   App::setLocale(session()->get('locale'));
}

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please explain your code to make it helpful for other users. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer https://stackoverflow.com/tour